# remove object added by this.add() - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, carousel

I am adding a carousel to my main Panel.

What I do is I create myCarousel with a toolbar and then I do:

```
this.add(myCarousel);
this.doLAyout();
```

this works fine, but later I need to redo myCarousel, for this I want to remove myCarousel from my main panel and then add it again and reder it.

I have tried

```
this.removeAll()
```

but it says that 'this.removeAll()' is undefined, even though when I inspect the item I can see that it has a removeAll() function listed in the **proto**

Is there a different way I should add/remove myCarousel object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can check this article: [Reload carousel items](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137081-Reload-carousel-items)

Comment: Thank you, but I posted that article.  And now I want to remove the whole carousel, not the cards in the carousel

Comment: Did you try : this.getItems().eq(myCarouselIndex).remove();

Comment: This is what I get for
this.getItems(),
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getItems'

Comment: ooops. I dont know your div structure etc. can you add scrollable() method before getItems.

Comment: is your this pointer pointing to the right object?  Not DOMWindow?

Comment: yes, it is not DOMWindow, I have checked in the console and myCarousel is an object of 'this'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
removeAll(true)
```

rather than

```
removeAll()
```

Comment: Thanks. This project I was working on was terminated a couple of months ago and I don't have the files anymore to try this solution. If you are able to confirm that this solution works I will mark the question as answered